# switch solution explorer to editor in vs 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

What is the keyboard shortcut or command for switching between the solution explorer and any of the editors in visual studio 2015? Can it be toggled?

I would like to search for this command in Options > Environment > Keyboard and assign a keyboard shortcut to the command.

Edit: 
I want the command to immediately switch view between solution explorer and e.g. the first (or previously used) tab on the editor.

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to switch to a code window from a tool window. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+L</kbd> to switch to Solution Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> and it is already there, if your solution explorer is open (e.g. in the active tools group).